# Flutter, setting positioned widgets dynamically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-positioned

I have a UI like

[image]

Now I want to create the letters on circle by given data. I need it to be a dynamic, when letters are less, (like 3 or 4) they must be far from each other. But, when they many (10 or 12) they must fit to circle (must have dynamic size and dynamic position).
The code of circle and letters -

```
Container(
            width: SizeConfig.devWidth! * 0.6,
            height: SizeConfig.devHeight! * 0.35,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
              color: MyColors.nextButtonColor,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Positioned(
                    top: SizeConfig.devHeight! * 0.04,
                    child: isDragging == true && isItemsDragging[0] != true
                        ? dragTargetWidget('Č', 0)
                        : draggableWord('Č', 0)),
                Positioned(
                    top: SizeConfig.devHeight! * 0.07,
                    right: SizeConfig.devWidth! * 0.1,
                    child: isDragging == true && isItemsDragging[1] != true
                        ? dragTargetWidget('É', 1)
                        : draggableWord('É', 1)),
                Positioned(
                    right: SizeConfig.devWidth! * 0.03,
                    child: isDragging == true && isItemsDragging[2] != true
                        ? dragTargetWidget('Ž', 2)
                        : draggableWord('Ž', 2)),
                Positioned(
                    bottom: SizeConfig.devHeight! * 0.07,
                    right: SizeConfig.devWidth! * 0.1,
                    child: isDragging == true && isItemsDragging[3] != true
                        ? dragTargetWidget('U', 3)
                        : draggableWord('U', 3)),
                Positioned(
                    bottom: SizeConfig.devHeight! * 0.04,
                    child: isDragging == true && isItemsDragging[4] != true
                        ? dragTargetWidget('T', 4)
                        : draggableWord('T', 4)),
                Positioned(
                    bottom: SizeConfig.devHeight! * 0.07,
                    left: SizeConfig.devWidth! * 0.1,
                    child: isDragging == true && isItemsDragging[5] != true
                        ? dragTargetWidget('Ě', 5)
                        : draggableWord('Ě', 5)),
                Positioned(
                    left: SizeConfig.devWidth! * 0.03,
                    child: isDragging == true && isItemsDragging[6] != true
                        ? dragTargetWidget('А', 6)
                        : draggableWord('А', 6)),
                Positioned(
                    top: SizeConfig.devHeight! * 0.07,
                    left: SizeConfig.devWidth! * 0.1,
                    child: isDragging == true && isItemsDragging[7] != true
                        ? dragTargetWidget('K', 7)
                        : draggableWord('K', 7)),
              ],
            ))
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

and my data is -

```
Crossword(type: "crossword", format: [
  "      š",
  "    žák",
  "      o",
  " učitel",
  "      a"
], chars: [
  "i",
  "e",
  "l",
  "a",
  "t",
  "o",
  "č",
  "k",
  "š",
  "á",
  "u",
  "ž"
], strings: {
  "škola": ["      *", "      *", "      *", "      *", "      *"],
  "žák": ["       ", "    ***", "       ", "       ", "       "],
  "učitel": ["       ", "       ", "       ", " ******", "       "]
}),
```

Any idea how can I achieve this? Any solution would be very useful, thanks!

Comment: see [RotaryDialDelegate](https://gist.github.com/pskink/50554a116698f03a862a356c38b75eb3#file-rotary_dial-dart-L114) - it is used as a `delegate:` for `CustomMultiChildLayout`

Comment: @pskink ok, I will try it, thank you

Comment: @pskink thank you so much!!! Write your answer please, It'll be a correct answer!

Comment: your welcome, write a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink! The solution is to use [RotaryDialDelegate](https://gist.github.com/pskink/50554a116698f03a862a356c38b75eb3#file-rotary_dial-dart-L114) as a delegate for CustomMultiChildLayout. Check the code below:

```
Container(
            width: SizeConfig.devWidth! * 0.6,
            height: SizeConfig.devHeight! * 0.35,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
              color: MyColors.nextButtonColor,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: CustomMultiChildLayout(
              delegate: RotaryDialDelegate(
                  wowProv.crosswordExercises[widget.indexLevel!].chars!.length),
              children: dragLetters
            ))
```